# How to hit break point in c++ app if it is not start-up project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I have a VS2010 solution that contain two projects: C# windows form & C++ console app. C# project is start-up project and it will call C++ app, I also set build priority and dependency correctly, but break point in c++ project won't get hit at debugging mode, here's my C# code:

```
static void Main()
{
    string CppPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString(), @"..\..\..") + @"\Debug\");
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(CppPath + "CommunicationServerCpp.exe");
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = CppPath;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);


    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

I don't want to separate them into two solutions,so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the debug menu there is "attach to process".

In the console project, you need to make a pause/delay function which waits until you attach the VS debugger.

It is not possible to debug 2 projects in 1 instance of VS - so a second instance has to be started.

Comment: "It is not possible to debug 2 projects in 1 instance of VS - so a second instance has to be started." Not sure what you mean by that. If you attach to process then you can debug your startup project and also your attached process in one instance.

Comment: I mean that You can't debug the C# application and at the same time attach to the C++ application.

Comment: I'm not sure what "pause/delay function" is, but it work!!... sad thing is that when hitting C++ proj break point, my C# form will be frozen like the UI thread is busying

Comment: In a GUI application I have a messagebox which waits until I press continue. In a console app a sleep function can be used. This gives time to find and attach to the appropriate process.

Comment: "It is not possible to debug 2 projects in 1 instance of VS" Sure it is - not 2 solutions, but 2 projects you can.  Just right click on the solution, properties - and select multi-project startup.  You can then have as many projects as you want start when you hit "run"